Shortcut to switch between Microsoft Edge windows
I have 5 windows open in microsoft Edge, each one has a unique web links and i need, for example, a shortcut using ALT+1 to always go to the first opened window,a shortcut ALT+2 to always go to the second opened window.
About the ALT+TAB will go always to the last opened window and it is not what i need.
I need a shortcut to go to a specific window opened in Microsoft Edge.
Does anyone know a way to do it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If Edge is pinned to Taskbar as first application - then Windows+1 can activate the fleet of Edge windows, then the relevant number of arrow key presses will get to 2nd,3rd etc. Edge window.
To use the arrow keys, press the alt key after the taskbar bundle is activated. Otherwise, repeated Windows+1 presses would be required, of course.

This is how you can do that, you need to create workspaces for that and do the following:
NOTE: You need auto hot key V2 to have this working.
The code below is a replica of the code on how to switch between the workspaces. It does the following things,
if the workspace isn't opened, it opens the workspace for you.
if the workspace has been opened/active (is available on the window), it will switch to that workspace.
You can have as many workspaces as you want, you have to just replace !1=>!2 in the first 2 lines and you're done!
Code
; Switch to the "Casual" workspace (Alt + 1)
!1:: ; Alt + 1
{
global
    if WinExist(" Casual")
    {
        WinActivate(" Casual")
    }
    else
    {
        Run("`"https://aka.ms/edge/workspaceslaunch?code=dHlwZT0xJmlkPWFIUjBjSE02THk5b2IyMWxMbTFwWTNKdmMyOW1kSEJsY25OdmJtRnNZMjl1ZEdWdWRDNWpiMjB2T25VNkwyY3ZZMjl1ZEdWdWRITjBiM0poWjJVdk5rTjZibWxvVGpOMk1IVjVNWHBMTlVaeVVrTmlkekZsTkRBd05XTTJOVEZtTmpaak1tSjNiM0pyYzNCaFkyVnpMMGxSU1ZwV1lqaHZSMUppZWxFM00xWXdXbFZ5WjBWMFJFRlZlVXd6U21GMU1qbGhibTVMV25Kak1EWjFOR3cwJnN0b3JlPTUmc291cmNlPVdvcmtzcGFjZXMmcmVkZWVtQ29kZT0mYXBwSWRHdWlkPWI2ZDgzM2NmLWI1NGUtNGNhYi04MTQzLTEzMThlMGJjNTBlMQ%3D%3D&source=Workspaces`"")
      }
    return

Explanation of the code:
You've to first state the name of the workspace. For me it was " Casual", But you can replace it anything you want. Then replace the name of your workspace with " Casual".
The second one is the link. you can get the link of your workspace from the invite section at the top of the edge (which allows you to share the link of your workspace for collaboration purposes). Then add the link inside the Run("`"yourWorkspaceLink``""). DON'T DELETE THE BRACES, THAT'S HOW IT WORKS, IT MIGHT LOOK WEIRD BUT THAT'S HOW THIS PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE WORKS.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
